# Django Admin extra forms with two widgets

Tags: python, django

In Django admin, I tried adding an extra field for my model like

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Provider

class IntervalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    @brief      Used to set the interval of each provider's queue task
    '''

    interval = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Provider
from .forms import IntervalForm

class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = IntervalForm

    list_display = ('code', '__unicode__', 'get_accounts', 'get_all_prefixes',
                    'get_columns')

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

This will work fine for now. But I want my extra 'interval' field to be like two fields. The first one is a select field with the options of 'minute', 'seconds' and 'hour' and the other one is an Integer Field..

I wist the fields with the label to be displayed as one-line as well

Comment: You'll need to do it as two fields. One is a ChoiceField and the other a CharField. Then create a function in your form called like `get_interval()` that uses the two field values to return the interval you want

Comment: Can it be displated in one field? Can you provide a code please?

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed? If you want a select and an int field it sounds like in the HTML you will have 2 fields, no?

Comment: exactly.. It should be two fields and then I will just concatenate the value on the backend

Comment: Right. So you will have 2 fields to accept input, and then a helper function in your modelform that you can use to take both inputs and return what you want.

Comment: Can you comment a code based on your idea?

Comment: Something like this in your class: https://repl.it/F8Ew/0